# Where to install SSL Cert

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I have Bluehost hosting my landing page and a few subdomains.  One of the subdomains has a A-Record that points to an Amazon EC2 instance running tomcat.  I would like the tomcat application to be hosted over HTTPS.  **Where do I need to install the certificate?  On Bluehost or in tomcat on my EC2 instance?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You install the certificate On Tomcat. See [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

In general terms you run the certificate on the device you want to handle HTTPS, which is the web server hosting the subdomain.   This is fairly intuitive as an SSL cert [usually] specifices a single domain, unless you get a wildcard cert or an SNI cert, in which case you would use it in both places.

Comment: BTW, you might have gotten a better response if your question was generic.  The exact same logic applies regardless of your web server or hosting provider.  A lot of people (myself included) have never heard of Bluehost, but it doesn't really make a difference to the answer.